# Laravel Eloquent With() With()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I go about using multiple Eloquent With()'s?

PortalPlaylistElement Model

```
class PortalPlaylistElement extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'code';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function AirtimePlaylists()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\AirtimePlaylist','id','playlist_id');
    }
}
```

AirtimePlaylistContent Model

```
class AirtimePlaylistContent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cc_playlistcontents';
}
```

AirtimePlaylistModel

```
class AirtimePlaylist extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cc_playlist';

    public function PortalPlaylistElements()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PortalPlaylistElement','playlist_id');
    }

    public function AirtimePlaylistContents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AirtimePlaylistContent','playlist_id');
    }
}
```

I have no problems with:

```
AirtimePlaylist::with('AirtimePlaylistContents')->get());
```

or

```
PortalPlaylistElement::with('AirtimePlaylists')->get();
```

But I'd like to get all AirtimePlaylistContents, in an AirtimePlaylist that belongs to a PortalPlaylistElement.

In essence, (Pseudo code)

```
PortalPlaylistElement::with('AirtimePlaylists')::with('AirtimePlaylistContents')->get();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need [Nested Eager Looading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
PortalPlaylistElement::with('AirtimePlaylists.AirtimePlaylistContents')->get();
```

Comment: Spot on - Have managed to further nest the additional models aswell. 

Thanks so much - I'll have a read up on them now I know what to look for!

Answer (score 12):

nested relations

```
 with('relation1.relation2.relation3')->get(); // relation1 has relation2 relation2 has relation 3
```

not nested relations

```
 with('relation1','relation2','relation3')->get(); // you model has all relations
```

Comment: but 'where clauses' inside 'with' seem to be ignored.. Anyone who knows how to deal with those cases?

Comment: can you show what you already tried? so i can get a better idea on what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add this if someone needed it

```
 with(['relation1.relation2-1','relation1.relation2-2'])->get(); // relation1 has relation2-1 and relation1 also has relation2-2
```